# Alternative of Paperclip as it is deprecated by thoughtbot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, paperclip, rails-activestorage

What are the good alternative for Paperclip gem as it is being deprecated by Thoughtbot in support of ActiveStorage but active storage is not that extensive as paperclip and there are lots of things which we can't do on active storage.

So my question is which other gem is more suitable as alternative of paperclip?

Comment: Why do you need a gem now as you mentioned rails itself giving the feature to upload through ActiveStorage? Anyway, CarrierWave is a popular alternative to the paperclip.

Comment: If we look into the implementation of active storage it does not provide manipulation of uploaded file like if we want to scale or convert image into multiple other size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not perform a feature comparison, but some alternatives are:

- [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)
- [DragonFly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly)